# Any automated tests available which can validate health of kubernetes cluster after the new deployment?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-health-check

Basically to verify all the components of  kube master and nodes up and running properly)  .. We follow delivery pipeline model to deploy on dev->devOps->staging->production ...manually verifying the clusters deployment in multiple of datacenter is time consuming ..   Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some e2e tests in kube that we run as a part of our release process, through Jenkins, Details of end-to-end tests are here:
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/devel/e2e-tests.md

Although we had to modify them a bit to test a few cases we wanted, specifically around the service with external load balancer.